# Using div background image as link using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have put a logo as the background image in a div

```
<div id="logo" style="background-image:url(images/logo.jpg); position:absolute; top:20px; left:18%; width:275px; height:100px; cursor:pointer;"></div>
```

I want to use this as div as a link using jquery

//jQuery code

```
$('#logo').bind('click',function() {
window.location = "index.php"
});
```

Neither does the `cursor:pointer` show up nor does the link work, any ideas.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Do you have any further info on this problem?   Using your examples, it works perfectly for me - both the cursor and link in both IE and Firefox.  Is your jQuery library correctly referenced on the page?

Comment: that should work, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W3c5V/)

Comment: I'm on chrome too... latest version and that works... was my demo not working in your browser?

Comment: see my example, it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you wrap your code in ***[ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)*** like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#logo').bind('click',function() {
    window.location = "index.php"
  });
});
```

Comment: @Jean: You need to specify wrap your code in ready handler so that when DOM becomes ready, your code should become runable when for example the logo gets clicked. More Info: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Jean: You have not specified the ready handler, note my first line please `$(function(){`

Comment: @sAc, I dont think this is needed in this case, because see my example it is working without the wrapping

Comment: @Starx: jsfiddle puts your code in ready handler implicitly when using jquery. Note from the left selection bar you have chosen load event.

Answer (score 1):

Register your `click` event handler in the `ready` event handler as follows, and it will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#logo").click(function() {
        window.location = "index.php";
    });
});
```

Regarding your CSS problem, I've tested it using Google Chrome (5.0.375.125), Opera (10.60), and Internet Explorer (8.0), and the cursor is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

add `display:block;` to your css

see an working example here

http://jsfiddle.net/4ceK4/

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
 window.location.replace("index.php")
```

instead of

```
 window.location = "index.php"
```

and instead of .bind, just use .click event.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need jQuery/JavaScript for that, just use HTML and CSS.

```
<a href="index.php" id="logo">Blabla</a>

#logo {
 display: block;
 background-image: url(img/foo.png);
 text-indent: -9999em;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 300px; /* width of image goes here */
 height: 300px; /* height of image goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are missing a semicolon after "index.php"